# Void Object created

Tags: c++, class, destructor

So, I have an exercise where I'm supposed to create a class creature.
It must have HP, a name, and a strength value.
That is done.
However, the creature is supposed to destroy itself if it's Hp or strength are out of specified boundaries (0-100 for the HP, 0-50 for the strength). In order to do that, I created a function that checks the creature's values and calls the destructor if the values are out of the boundaries.
It does work, but whenever it destroys the creature in the function, another void creature is destroyed at the end of the code execution.
Here is the console output :

```
Creature's name :Barbude
Creature's health (between 1 and 100) :50
Creature's strength (between 1 and 50) :52
Strength value incorrect.
Name : Barbude
HP : 50
Strength : 0
Barbude is destroyed.
 is destroyed.
```

To explain a little, the first 3 lines are for user input. The strength value is wrong. The console signals it at the next line. Therefore, the value is set to 0 (I made that in the setter), which destroys the creature.
Barbude is destroyed is what I expect to happen. But the last line means that that there is another object that I don't know how to get rid off.

I tried using the & to pass the creature by reference and not by value, but it doesn't work and the void object always appears.
Here i the code from the source file :

```
//from the source file.
void checkCreature(Creature& c) {
    if (c.getPV() == 0 || c.getPV() <= 0 || c.getStrength() > 100 || c.getStrength() <= 0) {
        c.~Creature();
    }
}


int main() {
    Creature c1;
    c1.fillCreature();
    c1.creatureShowInfo();
    checkCreature(c1);
        return 0;
}
```

```
Creature::~Creature()
{ 
    cout << name << " is destroyed." << endl;
}
```

English is not my native language, if something is unclear, please ask me for more informations.

Comment: `c.~Creature();` looks terribly wrong.

Comment: This looks like a homework written on old/early C++. Your professor most likely expects `new` for creation and `delete` for destruction. Won't make for nice code, but still better than calling the destructor directly

Comment: what is the exact text of your assignment? I am almost certain that you misunderstood something about  "the creature is supposed to destroy itself", because normally ojects dont control their own lifetime. They know how to destruct themself, but almost never they call their own destructor.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has UB. When you call destructor manually - which is not recommended in most cases -, the object won't disappear magically. You need to remove it from whatever container/storage you have it in, otherwise, at the end of the scope, the destructor is called again (which is a problem).
Normally, you'd likely store your creatures in some kind of container (say, `std::vector<Creature>`), so to remove a creature, you'd need to remove it from the container (say, `std::vector<Creature>`). You can do it either in `checkCreature()`, if you pass a reference to the container, or you might return a bool there, deciding whether to remove or keep the creature.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this. Actually, the whole exercise is to create a "fighting game" where creatures destroy each other. Whenever the creature loses all HP, the object is destroyed. So I intend to reuse the function later, which is why I put the destructor in it.

Comment: @HugoAngel You can reuse the function later without putting the dtor in it. Except for some very rare cases (e.g. implementing your own optional type - but why?) calling dtor manually is very bad practice (and is usually UB).

Comment: @HugoAngel destroying the object doesn't need to mean using the destructor, you could use a function called "destroy" and set a flag to indicate the object is destroyed

Comment: @Alan Birtles. this is actually the conclusion my classmates and I are coming to. Thank you for confirming it ! I'm going to go this way by using couts and written messages. Thank you for your answer. Last small question, what does UB mean ?

Comment: @HugoAngel undefined behaviour